Clicking on a button within an iframe with puppeteer
I'm trying to automate my browsing/reading of a news website (eenewseurope.com) to keep up to date with the most meaningful content. The cookies and newsletter pop-ups get in the way. I tried using the developer tools to isolate the iframes for those pop-ups but couldn't find them.
document.querySelector('cmplz-btn cmplz-accept') returns null

I used
const frame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'iframe');
const button = await frame.$('cmplz-btn cmplz-accept');
button.click();

Didn't work either.Threw that error.
file:///home/v/nTest.js:55
const button = await frame.$('cmplz-btn cmplz-accept');
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$')
at getNews (file:///home/v/nTest.js:55:32)
Node.js v20.16.0
And here's the code used :
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
const url = "https://eenewseurope.com";
const timeout = 200000;

async function getNews () {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
    timeout: 20000
    } );

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setViewport( {
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
} );

await page.goto( url, {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
    timeout: timeout,
} );

await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 12000));

const frame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'iframe');
const button = await frame.$('cmplz-btn cmplz-accept');
button.click();

}
};


getNews()

;
Any help would be appreciated,
Cheers

button.click(); needs to be awaited. I'm not sure what your main goal with this script is, though. Are you trying to scrape content? If so, what output do you expect? If you just want to manipulate the page for your reading convenience, Puppeteer feels like the wrong tool. I'd use a userscript, bookmarklet, or extension. Or even just an ad-blocker--I don't see any popups when I visit the site with uBlock Origin on Firefox. This is the best tool for blocking elements you don't want to see.

Thx @ggorlen. I am trying to screenshot the page with RPi using headless Chromium and Puppeteer. It works fine, but pop-ups on the page obfuscate part of the content. So I wanted to use Puppeteer to click on the accept button but the selector cannot be found. As mentioned above the document.querySelector() returns null.

OK, that makes sense. I don't see a page.screenshot() call. Can you add that along with your explanation from the comment? With that, the context for why you're doing this makes way more sense. Thanks.
